# Azure Func App queue trigger throwing encoding errors when trying to read the message

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App that is written in python. One function adds values to my Azure Storage Account Queue. The message body is a simple string of characters for example: `SS3`.

This function looks like:

```py
def main(scheduleImportSet: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    ...

    with DatabaseManager() as db:
        ...

        create_queue(queue_name)
        queue_client = QueueClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, queue_name)
        queue_client.message_encode_policy = BinaryBase64EncodePolicy()
        queue_client.message_decode_policy = BinaryBase64DecodePolicy()

        for set in set_data['data']:
            ...

            message_bytes = code.encode('utf-8')
            encoded_message = queue_client.message_encode_policy.encode(content=message_bytes)
            queue_client.send_message(encoded_message)
            ...
```

I have created a second function that is triggered based on the messages in the queue. I am trying to use the value in the message body to be used in the rest of the function.

```py
def main(queueImportSetCards: func.QueueMessage) -> None:
    start = time.perf_counter()
    logger.info('Get Set - Cards: Started.')

    message_content = queueImportSetCards.get_body().decode('utf-8')
    print(message_content)

    with DatabaseManager() as db:
        set_data = fetch_set_data(message_content)
        print(set_data)
```

```py
def fetch_set_data(code):
    url = API_BASE_URL + code + '.json'
    response = get_response(url)
    if response:
        try:
            set_data = response.json()
            return set_data ['data']
        except ValueError:
            logger.error(f"Failed to parse JSON data from {url}.")
    else:
        logger.error(f"Failed to get a valid response from {url}.")
    return {}
```

This is throwing the following error:

```
[2024-02-11T08:30:03.672Z] 2024-02-11 08:30:03,671 - ERROR - Error occurred: <class 'UnicodeEncodeError'> - 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2212' in position 3710: character maps to <undefined> for <traceback object at 0x000001D3864D6300>
[2024-02-11T08:30:03.674Z] Executed 'Functions.queue_import_sets_cards' (Failed, Id=950cc02b-2ef7-4290-b5ff-9a44b11d8141, Duration=209ms)
[2024-02-11T08:30:03.674Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.queue_import_sets_cards. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2212' in position 3710: character maps to <undefined>
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 479, in _handle__invocation_request
    call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
  File "C:\Users\Ross\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 752, in _run_sync_func
    return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context,
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper
    result = function(**args)
  File "C:\Users\Ross\OneDrive\Documents\Repositories\Func\queue_import_sets_cards\__init__.py", line 359, in main
    print(set_data)
  File "c:\Users\Ross\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2024.0.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_io.py", line 40, in write
    r.write(s)
  File "C:\Users\Ross\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
.
```

I have tried without the `decode()` but then there are issue as the message returns as `b'SS3'`

Answer (score 0):

***Updated solution:-***

You can adjust your Timer Trigger function to enqueue a fresh message for each iteration of your loop. This involves relocating the message creation inside the loop and assigning a new message for every iteration.

**`init.py:-`**

```py
import datetime
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.queue import QueueClient, BinaryBase64EncodePolicy

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest, outputQueueItem: func.Out[bytes]) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    if mytimer.past_due:
        print('The timer is past due!')

    # Assuming you have a loop to add 700 messages
    for i in range(700):
        message = "SSD" + str(i)  # You can modify the message content here
        encoded_message = message.encode('utf-8')
        outputQueueItem.set(encoded_message)
        print('Python timer trigger function ran at %s' % utc_timestamp)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

You can make use of the alternative code below to send a simple string body via **timer trigger** and receive it via **Queue trigger** by encoding and decoding it:-

***Timer Trigger:-***

**`init.py:-`**

```py
import datetime
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.queue import QueueClient, BinaryBase64EncodePolicy

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest, outputQueueItem: func.Out[bytes]) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    if mytimer.past_due:
        print('The timer is past due!')

    message = "SSD"
    encoded_message = message.encode('utf-8')
    outputQueueItem.set(encoded_message)
    print('Python timer trigger function ran at %s' % utc_timestamp)
```

**`function.json:-`**

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"  
    },
    {
      "name": "outputQueueItem",
      "type": "queue",
      "direction": "out",
      "queueName": "my-queue",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

***Queue Trigger:-***

**`init.py:-`**

```py
import logging

from azure.functions import QueueMessage


def main(msg: QueueMessage) -> None:
    logging.info('Python queue trigger function processed a queue item: %s',
                 msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

**`function.json:-`**

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "my-queue",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

**`requirements.txt:-`**

```
azure-functions
azure-storage-queue
```

***Output:-***

[image]

Comment: I have tried to implement you timer trigger changes. However, I am trying to add around 700 messages every time the timer trigger func runs. The `outputQueueItem.set()` seems to replace the previous message, and therefore there is only 1 in the queue once finished. Can we create a new message for each loop?

Comment: @Ross Check my updated solution in the answer.